# Embeding large arrays of objects in a Flutter application: android release is not built

Tags: android, arrays, flutter, dart, dart-isolates

The other day I came with a brilliant new idea ;) to improve performance of my flutter application.

I am developing an app which its main task is to let the user browse through a pretty large (let's say in scale of thousands) of simple data records. The source database is read-only and I do not need to update it. I noticed some lags and long waiting times while querying my SQLite database and could not improve it significantly applying database tricks (adding indices).

So here came my brilliant idea: Why shouldn't I convert these read-only records to hard-coded arrays of objects? I did it and got almost instant responses in the DEBUG mode (android application). But no matter how many times I tried and how many hours I waited I was not able to produce a RELEASE version (apk / multidex enabled).

So my question is: what was the problem? What happens for the final executable when you embed a huge array in your flutter code? Is this actually a good idea when performance matters and what are pros and cons? And why it had no problem creating an un-optimized (DEBUG) output? Is this a flutter bug for creating a release output in android?

Answer (score 1):

Querying a huge database is a heavy task that causes some lags in the application. You should run these heavy tasks in another Osolate so that it runs in another thread.
You can read more about Isolates [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/isolates-in-flutter-a0dd7a18b7f6).
If you are using drift to query database, you can read [this](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/advanced-features/isolates/)

Comment: Thanks Mahdi, but this does not answer my main question which is this part: What happens for the final executable when you embed a huge array in your flutter code (why I could not build a release version while having no problem debugging)?

Comment: I think not being able to build release apk is not related to hardcoding huge arrays of objects. can you provide the error you get while building release apk?

Comment: There is no error. It only takes a long time to build and never builds a release apk.

Comment: it's because of your internet connection or a proxy issue. if you are using a proxy or a VPN, just change it and while building apk wait for a few more minutes and let flutter download its nessesary packages to build release apk. also for solving application lag while loading data, it's not a good practice to hard code the data. the better solution is to use isolates. if this helps, please consider accepting my answer